# How to get pointer events in flutter from touch events that originated outside of the container?

Tags: flutter

I have a `Draggable` container, and another container that is supposed to get position of draggable content.

```
    return SizedBox.expand(
  child: Column(
    children: <Widget>[
      Draggable(
        child: Container(
          width: 50,
          height: 56,
          color: Colors.orange,
        ),
        feedback: Container(
          width: 50,
          height: 56,
          color: Colors.orange,
        ),
      ),
       SizedBox.fromSize(
         size: Size(500, 500),
         child: Listener(
           onPointerSignal: (PointerSignalEvent details) => print('get updates here'),
           child: Container(
             color: Colors.pink.withOpacity(0.2),
           ),
       ),
        ),
    ],
  ),
);
```

How to receive any movement on top of a container? `onPanUpdate` works only for pan originated in that container.
The same goes for `onPointerMove` from `Listener`.

Comment: What is it you're trying to achieve overall? Do you have an example or illustration?